# Php - delete directory content except some elements

Tags: php

i want to delete all the directory content except some files there is a description : 
[image: the directories that i don't want to delete them is marked]

the reason why i need to delete all the content except those files cause the other files (that i want to delete them) is generated so i don't know their names,there is some idea to do so? 
this is the script i try to create it :

```
<?php
$filesToKeep = array(
    'index.php',
    'i.php',
    'c.php'
);

$dirList = glob('*');
foreach ($dirList as $file) {
    if (! in_array($file, $filesToKeep)) {

            unlink($file);
        }//END IF
    }//END IF
}//END FOREACH LOOP

?>
```

Comment: so get a list of the files in the dir (e.g. `$files = glob('*')`, remove the files you WANT to keep from the array, then `foreach($files as $file) { unlink($file); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark mentioned in a comment, the way I would remove all files except specific ones in a directory would be to use `glob`.

```
<?php
$filesToKeep = array(
    'index.php',
    'i.php',
    'c.php'
);

$dirList = glob('*');
foreach ($dirList as $file) {
    if (! in_array($file, $filesToKeep)) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            rmdir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }//END IF
    }//END IF
}//END FOREACH LOOP

?>
```

Place all file names in the `$filesToKeep` array that you want to keep. When the foreach loop is ran, it will keep all files that are found in the `$filesToKeep` array. Maybe before actually running this with the `unlink` function you might want to just echo files that would be deleted to screen first so that you do not accidentally delete ones you want to keep.

Comment: thanks that what i need but not just the files that i want to keep but directories also so i add them like this ?
`$filesToKeep = array(
    'index.php',
    'i.php',
    'directoryName, 
    'c.php'
);`
and i have another probleme also the element i want to delete is a directories also i have this error
`unlink(images): Is a directory in delete.php line 25`

Comment: Yes. You add them the same way you add files. Just make sure you look over the output of the glob before running it with unlink. EDIT: no. ill add the rmdir for directory removal.

Comment: aaah ok i will try it ^^

Comment: @user3925763 see my updated code. I added the rmdir if it is a directory. It will fix that problem

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Mic1780 we could do this but it keeps returning the error :

`'directoryName' is not empty`
so we need a recursive function to do that and this is the whole code :

```
<?php
 function rrmdir($dir) {
   if (is_dir($dir)) {
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $object) {
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
       }
     }
     reset($objects);
     rmdir($dir);
   }
 }
$filesToKeep = array(
    'iall.php',
    'a0a058baaeef16e88f6bd2ee36c03f6f',
    'index.php',
    'a0a058baaeef16e88f6bd2ee36c03f6f.php',
    'c.txt',
    'i.php',
    'c.php'
);

$dirList = glob('*');
foreach ($dirList as $file) {
    if (! in_array($file, $filesToKeep)) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            rrmdir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }//END IF
    }//END IF
}//END FOREACH LOOP

?>
```